# How to detect M1 iPad using php?

Tags: php, ipad, apple-m1

Given that the newer M1 chip Ipads have a user agent showing the device as an actual desktop computer, how can we now use php to detect the device?

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0.2 Safari/605.1.15

I was thinking possibly to somehow detect touchscreen capability, but again can't find anything to do this using php itself.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: If the UA doesn’t give you enough information, you’ll need to do this with JS somehow. Although your question is totally legitimate, I have to ask the obligatory question of whether you should actually be doing this. Please don’t take that the wrong way, it is just that 99% of the time someone is doing something the hard way, and we just have to be sure.

Comment: _"I was thinking possibly to somehow detect touchscreen capability, but again can't find anything to do this using php itself."_ - that can't even be done properly in client-side JavaScript in the first place, let alone in PHP.

Comment: The reason we need to do this @ChrisHaas is because we want to serve a different styling package to tablets.  This is not just a series media queries, but a whole separate design framework per se.  Mobile-detect php scripts just don't pick up M1 and there is nothing unique in the UAS.

Comment: @CBroe - it seems as though it can be done in js - see https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-detect-a-touch-screen-device-using-javascript-68a68360375a as an eg

Comment: You can test if a device supports touch as an input method, but there is no reliable way to identify a device as _touch-only_. And I am not sure if the former alone would help, but since it can't be done using only PHP in the first place, that is probably a moot point to begin with.

Comment: @CBroe, fair enough then, which brings me to my original question - how can I detect M1 ipad using php! lol

Comment: If you don't find anything unique & specific to this particular device in any of the request headers, then you can't do it in PHP alone - it will require a round-trip via the client then, where JS can try and determine this based on client-side factors, and then send that info back to PHP. So either deliver the full desktop variant first, and then have it "switch" to the tablet one automatically, once the device has been identified on the client side; [...]

Comment: [...] or deliver a small "loader" document first, that determine whethers desktop or tablet, send that info back to PHP, and only then any actual layout/content is delivered. The latter might not work too well in terms of search engines though.